# Mapping multiple columns to a single dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe (e.g., `df3`) that overwrites salary information onto people's names. I currently working with df1 with a list of around 1,000 names. Here's an example of what df1 looks like.

```
    print df1.head() 

               Salary
    Name       
    Joe Smith  8700
    Jane Doe   6300
    Rob Dole   4700
    Sue Pam    2100
    Jack Li    3400
```

I also have `df2`, which randomly assigns people from `df1` as either Captain and Skipper columns.

```
    print df2.head()

    Captain    Skipper
    Sue Pam    Joe Smith
    Jane Doe   Sue Pam
    Rob Dole   Joe Smith
    Joe Smith  Sue Pam
    Rob Dole   Jack Li
```

How can I replace the names in `df2` with their corresponding salaries so that I have this exact format below. In excel, I would use a VLOOKUP function, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this using Python.

```
print df3.head()   

    Captain    Skipper
    2100       8700
    6300       2100
    4700       8700
    8700       2100
    4700       3400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df2[col].map(df1['Salary'])` to map each column of `df2` according to `df1['Salary']`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Salary':[8700,6300,4700,2100,3400]}, index=pd.Series(['Joe Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Rob Dole', 'Sue Pam', 'Jack Li'], name='Name'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Captain':['Sue Pam', 'Jane Doe',  'Rob Dole', 'Joe Smith', 'Rob Dole'], 'Skipper': ['Joe Smith',  'Sue Pam', 'Joe Smith', 'Sue Pam', 'Jack Li']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({col: df2[col].map(df1['Salary']) for col in df2})
print(df3)
```

yields

```
   Captain  Skipper
0     2100     8700
1     6300     2100
2     4700     8700
3     8700     2100
4     4700     3400
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the salary for each name in `df1` with `df1.loc[name, 'Salary']`.
Using [`.applymap()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap), you can do this for  all entries in all columns of `df2`:

```
df3 = df2.applymap(lambda x: df1.loc[x, 'Salary'])
print(df3)
```

Result:

```
    Captain  Skipper
0     2100     8700
1     6300     2100
2     4700     8700
3     8700     2100
4     4700     3400
```

Comment: Worked, as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd leverage the [`pd.Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) feature combined with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to make `df2` a series.  Then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) back.

- `stack` `df2` to make it a series
- use `map` with `df1.Salary`
- `unstack` to get back your dataframe

---

```
df2.stack().map(df1.Salary).unstack()

   Captain  Skipper
0     2100     8700
1     6300     2100
2     4700     8700
3     8700     2100
4     4700     3400
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`dataframe.replace` method is more suitable than doing lookup.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Salary':[8700,6300,4700,2100,3400]}, index=pd.Series(['Joe Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Rob Dole', 'Sue Pam', 'Jack Li'], name='Name'))
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Captain':['Sue Pam', 'Jane Doe',  'Rob Dole', 'Joe Smith', 'Rob Dole'], 'Skipper': ['Joe Smith',  'Sue Pam', 'Joe Smith', 'Sue Pam', 'Jack Li']})
>>> df2.replace(df1.Salary)
   Captain  Skipper
0     2100     8700
1     6300     2100
2     4700     8700
3     8700     2100
4     4700     3400
```